# An Example of Nonlinear Optimization with JuMP

Tags: julia, nonlinear-optimization

As a test in understanding nonlinear optimization using Julia's JuMP modeling language, I am trying to minimize the Rosenbrock function in 10 dimensions with constraints `0 <= x[i] <= 0.5`. First Rosenbrock with variable arguments:

```
function rosen(x...)
    local n = length(x); local s = 0.0
    for i = 1:length(x)-1
        s += 100*(x[i+1] - x[i]^2)^2 + (x[i] - 1)^2
    end
    return s
end
## rosen (generic function with 1 method)
```

Define the optimization model with Ipopt as solver,

```
using JuMP; using Ipopt
m = Model(solver = IpoptSolver())
## Feasibility problem with:
## * 0 linear constraints
## * 0 variables
## Solver is Ipopt
```

and the variables with bound constraints and starting values `x[i] = 0.1`:

```
@variable(m, 0.0 <= x[1:10] <= 0.5)
for i in 1:10 setvalue(x[i], 0.1); end
```

Now I understand that I have to register the objective function.

```
JuMP.register(m, :rosen, 10, rosen, autodiff=true)
```

I am uncertain here whether I can do it like this, or if I need to define and register a `mysquare` function, as is done in the "User-defined Functions" section of the JuMP manual.

```
@NLobjective(m, Min, rosen(x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10]))
```

How can I write this more compactly? An expression like

```
@NLobjective(m, Min, rosen(x[1:10]))
##ERROR: Incorrect number of arguments for "rosen" in nonlinear expression.
```

gives an error. What if I would like to solve this problem with 100 variables?

Now we solve this model problem and, alas, it returnes a solution, and indeed the correct solution as I know from solving it with the NEOS IPOPT solver.

```
sol = solve(m);
## ...
## EXIT: Optimal Solution Found.
```

As I am only interested in the exact value of x[10], extracting it thus:

```
getvalue(x[10]
## 0.00010008222367154784
```

Can this be simplified somehow? Think of it how easy it is to solve this problem with `fminsearch` in MATLAB or `optim` in R.

```
R> optim(rep(0.1,10), fnRosenbrock, method="L-BFGS-B",
         lower=rep(0.0,10), upper=rep(0.5,10),
         control=list(factr=1e-12, maxit=5000))
## $par
## [1] 0.50000000 0.26306537 0.08003061 0.01657414 0.01038065
## [6] 0.01021197 0.01020838 0.01020414 0.01000208 0.00000000
```

Except, of course, it says `$par[10]` is 0.0 which is not true.

Comment: Possibly related to: [Julia+JuMP: variable number of arguments to function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44710900/juliajump-variable-number-of-arguments-to-function/44711305#44711305)

Comment: @DanGetz : This is a bloody trick, `setNLobjective` is not even exported from JuMP. I really don't understand what this `Expr` does, though it appears to work. Should there not be an easier approach for the casual user? -- as this is likely a common problem for every use of JuMP for nonlinear minimization.?

Comment: Here is some brief explanation. What @NLobjective does is similar to R's non-standard evaluation, and setNLobjective is the corresponding function doing the real work, `Expr` thing is just to make the expression object `rosen(x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10])`, in R it is like that you are constructing `quote(rosen(x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5],x[6],x[7],x[8],x[9],x[10]))`. I'm not sure but maybe we could post some issue and make a PR on this? Shouldn't be too difficult.